# Highlight cell with highest value in ng-repeat with AngularJS 1.4.14

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a dashboard and I'd like some help '_'.

I get a JSON from an API and I get an array of 5 element and each contain this structure (I simplified it but it is close to that).

```
{
      "app_id": "id",
      "app_name": "name",
      "users_percentiles": {
        "users_percentile_1": "3408",
        "users_percentile_2": "2356",
        "users_percentile_3": "988",
        "users_percentile_4": "1099",
      }
    }
```

Then, I use a table to organize those elements in my dashboard.

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="dash in dashboard">
            <tr>
                <td>{{dash.app_id}}</td>
                <td>{{dash.app_name}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="percentile in dash.users_percentiles">
                    {{(percentile}}%
                </td>
           </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I'd like for each ng-repeat highlight the highest value of percentile (if two are equals, then both should be highlighted).

I think i should add something like :

```
ng-class="{max : percentile == maxPercentile}"
```

and a function :

```
     $scope.maxPercentile = -1;
     angular.forEach(percentiles, function (percentile) {
         if (percentile > $scope.maxPercentile) {
             $scope.maxPercentile = percentile;
         }
     });
```

But I don't know really where to use this method.

I tried with a $watch but no matter how I tried I didn't get it to work...

Comment: Can the percentiles change after you retrieve the JSON?

Comment: The dashboard is refreshed every 5min with a new call to the API. The values change only at this moment.

Comment: You seem to be headed in the right direction then. Just call your code to calculate the maxPercentile after you retrieve the data.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks to you and Jins Peter ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tbody ng-repeat="dash in dashboard">
            <tr>
                <td>{{dash.app_id}}</td>
                <td ng-init = "maxpercentile = getMaxPercentile(dash.users_percentiles)">{{dash.app_name}}</td>

                <td ng-class="{max : percentile === maxpercentile}"
                  ng-repeat="percentile in dash.users_percentiles">
                    {{percentile}}%
                </td>

           </tr>
    </tbody>



$scope.getMaxPercentile = function(percentiles){
         var maxPercentile = -1;
         angular.forEach(percentiles, function (percentile) {
             if (percentile > $scope.maxPercentile) {
                 maxPercentile = percentile;
             }
         });
         return maxPercentile;
    }
```

Comment: At first, it highlighted random number xD.
but after some parseInt, It worked. Thanks

Comment: Oh. yeah,, you have to parse. :)